# Spatstat What is the scale used on the colour bar when plotting a point pattern?

Tags: spatstat

I am plotting a spatial point pattern of about 11000 points, in a rectangular area with limits c(0,100), c(0,70).

I wanted to check the interpretation of the scale on the color bar. The color bar scale runs from 0 to about four. Do these numbers represent points per unit area, where the total area = 100 x 70?

Answer (score 1):

When you plot a point pattern of class `ppp` using `plot()` (dispatching to `plot.ppp()`) no color bar is produced. Please explain what you are doing with a reproducible example. Just use a built-in dataset like `cells` to illustrate the problem/question. Maybe you are plotting an estimate of the point intensity/density obtained by `density()` (dispatching to `density.ppp()`)? By default the result from running `density.ppp()` is a raster/image of class `im` and in this case the color bar produced by `plot.im()` indeed represents number of points per unit area.

Comment: Thanks @egerubak. I was indeed plotting a density. I was using `plot(density(cells))`